# How to get all item selected into ListBox ( Multiple Selection ) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, multi-select

I would like to select multiple data from a listbox

The code below work fine for Single Selection: `0 -fmMultiSelectSingle`

```vb
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Msg = "You selected:" & vbNewLine
    For i = 1 To ListBox1.ListCount
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            Msg = Msg & ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine                         
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox Msg
    ListBox1.Selected(0) = False
End Sub
```

The messagebox displays me the slected item, but if I switch the MultiSelect option to:

`1 - fmMultiSelectMulti` or `2 - fmMultiSelectExtended`, the previous code isn't working: The message box displays nothing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Vityata The error resume next was to handle the error for  the if one item of this list box is selected then unselect other item of other listbox .. i edited my post so there is no confusion possible. Thanks

Comment: this way the question seems better :)

Comment: i must start at 0 and end at listbox1.count-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event should be `_Change` and not `_Click`, as far as it does not enter it, in the case of `fmMultiSelectExtended` due to some strange reason. Or try the other built-in events in the VBE, available from the dropdown:

[image]

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

    Dim myMsg As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            myMsg = myMsg & ListBox1.List(i) 
        End If
    Next i

    Debug.Print myMsg

End Sub
```

Just consider the fact, that if you select 3 values after each other, every time there would be only 1 selected value. Thus, you would get 3 different sets of data in the immediate window. Like this:

[image]

For this `ListBox`:

[image]

Comment: @Viyata Thanks,But is there a way to store all the selected item into an array ? I tried this : `Dim Filtre() As Variant
    
    Count = 1' Before the loop
            ReDim Preserve Filtre(Count) ' In the For If
            Filtre(Count) = ListBox1.List(i)'In the For If
            Count = Count + 1'In the For If` But this definitly don't work

Comment: @Dorian - there should be a way, I am afk now, but ask a new question, you would probably get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following Code to Store all value of selected items in listbox

```
Public Function listASIN() As String
Dim ctl As Control
Dim strASIN As String

Set ctl = Me!lstASIN

strASIN = ""

' Now select what records from listbox
If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then
    i = 1
    For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
        strASIN = strASIN & ctl.ItemData(varItem) & ","
        i = i + 1
    Next varItem
Else
    Exit Function
End If

'Remove Last "," from ASIN list
strASIN = Left(strASIN, Len(strASIN) - 1)

listASIN = strASIN
End Function
```